# How to run multiple commands in cmd

Tags: windows, cmd

I am trying to write a batch file to run several WORD and POWERPOINT file as below:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" "D:\Files\Literature\Literature Review\Literature-Review.docx" & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" "D:\Files\Literature\Literature Review\outline.docx" & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" "D:\Files\Literature\Questions to be asked\Questions to be asked.docx" & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" "D:\Files\Presaentationen\1. Gruppemeeting\ToDo.docx" & "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\POWERPNT.exe" "D:\Files\Presaentationen\1. Gruppemeeting\Presentation_Englisch.pptx"
```

The problem is that only the first file opens. If I close it the next one opens and so on. But I want to open them all at the same time. What should I do? (OS is Windows 7)

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" "filename1" "filename2" ...
```

should open each file in winword.

If you wish to open powerpoint as well, you'd need to `start` each executable

```
start "windowtitle" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" "filename1" "filename2" ...
start "windowtitle" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\POWERPNT.exe "filename3"
```

**but** you would need to add the `/w` switch to the last executable you start this way, otherwise the commands following will be excuted (which you may not want)

Furthermore, the batch would then proceed when the `wait`ed application terminates, so

```
start "windowtitle" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE" "filename1" "filename2" ...
start /w "windowtitle" "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\Office14\POWERPNT.exe "filename3"
```

would wait until powerpoint exits and then proceed, regardless of whether winword is still open.

`windowtitle` may be empty, but should not be omitted (ie. use `""` if you want, but don't leave out this element)

Comment: Yes it worked. thank you very much. I didn't get this part about `/w`: `otherwise the commands following will be excuted (which you may not want).`

Answer (score 0):

When `cmd` runs a GUI application it does not wait for it to complete. (Whether an application is windowed (GUI) or console is determined by a flag in its exe file.)

But you can use

```
start /wait SomeGuiApp
```

to force `cmd` to wait.

However you appear to have the oposite problem: it could be that `&`. It is designed for conditionally performing one action dependent on the return value from the previous. But return values are not really meaningful for GUI apps.

Why not run them as separate commands: on different lines of the `cmd` script or separated (IIRC) by a semicolon.

Remember, with command extensions on you can use parentheses to have multiple lines under the control of `if` etc.

Comment: `&&` conditionally executes a command if the previous command succeeded, but `&` just executes commands sequentially. It shouldn't wait for a GUI program to exit before executing the next command in the sequence.

Comment: I just checked how `&&` works in the debugger. `cmd!eAnd` first dispatches the left-hand side via `cmd!Dispatch`, and then if it succeeds (e.g. the program exit code is 0) it dispatches the right-hand side. But dispatching a GUI program doesn't wait for the exit code; it always succeeds and thus always executes the right-hand side. So for GUI programs `&&` is effectively the same as `&`.